# Call C# method with string from c++

Tags: c#, c++, string

I know similar things has been asked before but I just cant get it to work..
I have a c# function in a dll.

```
    public int setUser(string str){
```

I am calling this from c++.
I tried something like this.

```
    long lResult = 0; 
    PWSTR pw = L"hello";
    pICalc->setUser(pw, &lResult);
```

But it seems this just sends in an empty string or a null value.

What is the easiest way to call the method and send in a String that the method will get?

Comment: How do you even call the method? Are you using C++/CLI? Or COM?

Comment: Hello
I use COM

Comment: So what exactly happens? Do you get `null` in C#? Or an empty string? What happens if you return 42 regardless of input, does that make the trip back to C++? How does your COM interface look like? Both in C# and C++?

Comment: It is an empty string. Yes I can pass ints between them with no problem. It is just Strings that I do not understand how to get to work.

Comment: About the interface I am not exactly sure, I used this tutorial to get it working:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With COM, strings are marshaled as BSTRs, which is different from a null-terminated C++ string. The easiest way to make a BSTR in C++ is with ATL's CComBSTR class:

```
pICalc->setUser(CComBSTR(L"hello"), &lResult);
```

Otherwise you can use the SysAllocString/SysFreeString functions:

```
BSTR bstrString = ::SysAllocString(L"hello");
if (bstrString == NULL)
    // out of memory

pICalc->setUser(bstrString, &lResult);
::SysFreeString(bstrString);
```